# active admin association not showing dropdown list of category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have create two model Category and Blog where blog has 1 category and category belong to blog.
Now when I use active admin panel form to perform crud operations then blog form doesn't showing drop-down with category options

```
Blog model

class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :category
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

```
category model

class Category < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :blog
    attr_accessor :category_type
end
```

```
admin/blog.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Blog do
  # ent all parameters which should be permitted for assignment
    #
    permit_params :title, :*********, :******, :category_id, :*****, :*********
    #
    index do
      selectable_column
      id_column
      column :title
      column :******
      column :******
      column :category_id
      column :*****
      column :*****
      actions
    end
  ]

    form do |f|
      f.inputs do
        f.input :title
        f.input :********
        f.input :*******
        f.input :category_id
        f.input :******
        f.input :image, as: :file
      end
      f.actions
    end
  end
```

is there any solution or correction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the ActiveRecord relationship you need to register the belongs_to with ActiveAdmin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Blog do
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
```

See [the ActiveAdmin documentation](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#belongs-to) for more details.

Comment: it gives me an error message:  `Started GET "/admin/blogs/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-11 08:53:43 +0530
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admin/blogs/new"):`

Comment: Use optional true if you want to use admin/blogs/new

Comment: Use `f.input :category`

Comment: what about child category if category has self association